# Android: download theme?

Tags: android

Currently my android has black background and white foreground(text color), I want to change it to some other theme, is there any market available that I can download theme xml files that can be used in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to download the light theme in order to use it. It comes with the system. You just need to indicate in your manifest that you'd like your activity to be shown with the light theme. Here is an example:

```
    <activity android:name="NoteEditor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
    >
```

Comment: Although marked as the answer, it's not really an answer to his question. So, do you happen to know any place where one can buy/download Android Themes and/or Styles?

Comment: I do not. If you are looking for these to apply to your phone as a user you'll have better luck at Android.stackexchange.com StackOverflow is for programming specific questions.